# cachedThreadPool not working as I expected

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I'm playing around with threads and I don't understand why this isn't working as I thought.

I am trying to calculate a sum using threads and was expecting for the thread pool to wait for all tasks to finish by the time I print out the result (due to the shutdown() call and the isTerminated() check).

What am I missing here?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test5 {

private Integer sum= new Integer(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 
    Test5 obj = new Test5();

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            pool.execute(obj.new Adding());
    }

    pool.shutdown();

    while(!pool.isTerminated()) {
        //could be empty loop...
        System.out.println(" Is it done? : " + pool.isTerminated());
    }

    System.out.println(" Is it done? : " + pool.isTerminated());
    System.out.println("Sum is " + obj.sum);                
}

class Adding implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        synchronized(this) {

            int tmp = sum;
            tmp+=1;
            sum=new Integer(tmp);           
        }                       
    }               
}
}
```

While I do get good results, I also get output such as this:

```
Is it done? : true
Sum is 983
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues.

1. Your code **is not threadsafe**
2. Busy waiting is an anti-pattern to be avoided.

What do i mean by 1.?

Lets suppose we have two threads, A & B.

1. A reads `sum` into `tmp` as 1
2. B reads `sum` into `tmp` as 1
3. A increments `sum` to 2
4. A writes `sum` as 2
5. B increments `sum` to 2
6. B writes `sum` as 2

So we end up with 2 after two increments. No quite right.

Now you may say "but I have used `synchronized`, this should not happen". Well, you haven't.

When you create your `Adding` instances you `new` each one. You have 1000 separate `Adding` instances.

When you `synchronized(this)` you are synchronizing on the current instance, **not** across all `Adding`. So your synchronized block does nothing.

Now, the *simple* solution would be to use `synchronized(Adding.class)`.

The `synchronized(Adding.class)` will make the code block synchronized correctly across all `Adding` instances.

The *good* solution would be to use an `AtmoicInteger` rather than an `Integer` as this increments atomically and is designed for exactly this sort of task.

Now onto 2.

You have a `while(thing){}` loop, this basically runs the thread like crazy testing thousands of times a millisecond until `thing` is `true`. This is **a huge waste** of CPU cycles. An `ExecutorService` has a special, blocking, method that waits until it has shutdown, `awaitTermination`.

Here is an example:

```
static final AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        pool.execute(new Adding());
    }

    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    System.out.println(" Is it done? : " + pool.isTerminated());
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
}

static class Adding implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        sum.addAndGet(1);
    }
}
```

I would also suggest not using a `cachedThreadPool` in this circumstance as you have 1000 `Runnable`s being submitted and this will generate far more `Thread`s than you have CPUs. I would suggest using `newFixedThreadPool` with a sane number of `Thread`s.

I'm not even going to go into the use of `int` literals and `Integer` and why `new Integer()` is not needed.

Comment: Normal increments are typically atomic. The problem likely has to do with thread caching and I believe he could get the same effect as your code snippet by adding the volatile keyword to his sum variable, forcing a direct memory lookup like AtomicInteger does.

Comment: You are right, modern JVMs do  implement `int++` atomically. But the OP's code would not work with `volatile` due to the use of `tmp`. Furthermore the JLS provides no guarantees of the atomicity of incrementation so it is best not to assume that the implementation is the same across all platforms.

Comment: Wow, there is so much more to this. Thanks for making it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sync on the main object instance. I'm using `int` below, Integer will work too (needs to initialized to zero explicitly).

Here is the working code

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class AppThreadsSum {

    int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        AppThreadsSum app = new AppThreadsSum();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            pool.execute(app.new Adding());
        }

        pool.shutdown();

        while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
            System.out.println(" Is it done? : " + pool.isTerminated());
        }

        System.out.println(" Is it done? : " + pool.isTerminated());
        System.out.println("Sum is " + app.sum);
    }

    class Adding implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            synchronized (AppThreadsSum.this) {

                sum += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. Busy waiting is an anti-pattern to be avoided (copied from the neighbor answer to be complete and aware of this important thing, see comments)

Comment: You should explain what volatile does for the OP.

Comment: I would really recommend against busy-waiting. This should never be done.

Comment: @JesanFafon  oops, `volatile` is not needed here since `synchronized` is used. `volatile` ensures that the value is not copied to the thread local area and the same value is available to all threads.

Comment: @bmorris591 yes, but the question was about why "it's not waiting". It actually waited but the synchronization happened on the wrong object.

Comment: Yeah, it will wait - but it will busy wait. I think it's good to point these things out as and when they arise otherwise you may one day find this code in your own code pool...

Comment: @bmorris591 Agreed (twice already :), if you do not mind I just copy-paste "Busy waiting is an anti-pattern to be avoided" from you answer to p.s. section.